# Safari lodge vehicle allocations - resource constraint / allocation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I work in a safari lodge where we need to continuously allocate guests to vehicles for the duration of their stay, with the following contraints:

- no more than 6 guests allocated to a vehicle at any time
- guests must be allocated to the same vehicle for the duration of their stay
- where a guest (or group of guests) pays for a private vehicle, no other guests may be allocated to that vehicle
- private vehicle bookings impact the remaining number of vehicles available for allocation
- guests travelling together must be allocated to the same vehicle(s)
- the maximum number of available vehicles is fixed (=5)
- the maximum number of potential guests to be allocated is fixed (=24)
- at times, certain vehicles may be unavailable for a period
- allocations are updated daily for latest + last minute bookings and must take into account the existing allocation configuration for the current day when updating forward into the future (i.e. tomorrow onwards)
- the goal is to minimize the number of vehicles in use at any point, without having to break up groups or move guests from one vehicle to another during their stay.

I've come across a range of algorithmic approaches, from resource scheduling to greedy algorithms - but realistically I'm not technical enough to evaluate what I need and how it needs to hang together. I have some basic coding experience in Javascript and VBA (*shudder*), but I'm not especially mathematical. Viewing this as an interesting learning exercise that could make life a lot easier if I can find a way to automate much of the allocation logic. I can't quite formulate a 'picture' of the problem/approach in my mind - whether it's a large matrix or some kind of tree?

Ideally, I'd be able to generate an algorithmic solution that would give me 90% of what I need, which I could then tweak manually (and minimally) for a final solution, taking into account the particular idiosyncrasies of certain guests or groups. This final solution would then need to be the input (starting point) to the next allocation update when the most recent list of (updated) bookings is received.

It's very possible that this problem is too complex for my technical abilities - but I won't know until I ask! Many thanks.

Comment: A constraint solver algorithm might be a good place to start. https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp is available in several languages.

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer, will take a look 